# EUI-64 on a loopback address

Tags: ipv6, packet-tracer, loopback

A loopback address does not have a MAC address. How then does a loopback interface get assigned an EUI-64 address? I ran an example on packet tracer, and the loopback interface successfully acquired a link-local address and a global unicast address. The 48 of 64 bits used for EUI portion used an address which I could not find on any interface. The topology used in packet tracer is in the picture below.

[image]

Here is the output of `show ipv6 interface brief` for R3:

```
GigabitEthernet0/0/0       [up/up]
    FE80::2D0:D3FF:FE48:C01
    2001:ABCD:ABCD:0:2D0:D3FF:FE48:C01
GigabitEthernet0/0/1       [administratively down/down]
    unassigned
Loopback0                  [up/up]
    FE80::290:21FF:FE4D:70D2
    2001:AAAA:AAAA:AAAA:290:21FF:FE4D:70D2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually mean a *Modified* EUI-64 address. An EUI-64 address is an address assigned by the manufacturer to an interface that uses 64-bit MAC addresses. Having a MAC address is not a requirement for a SLAAC-assigned address. Most modern OSes use [Privacy Extensions with Random Addressing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4941), and the original SLAAC addressing based on MAC addressing is mostly outdated.

Even the original SLAAC addressing did not require a MAC address, but a MAC address is a convenient number that should be unique on a LAN. Not all data-link protocols use MAC addressing (only the IEEE protocols do). Some, like PPP, do not even use addressing. *[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291)* Appendix A explains how to derive an address for the original SLAAC. Notice that it does not require MAC addressing:

> Appendix A: Creating Modified EUI-64 Format Interface Identifiers
>
> Depending on the characteristics of a specific link or node, there are
> a number of approaches for creating Modified EUI-64 format interface
> identifiers. This appendix describes some of these approaches.
>
> Links or Nodes with IEEE EUI-64 Identifiers
>
> The only change needed to transform an IEEE EUI-64 identifier to an
> interface identifier is to invert the "u" (universal/local) bit. An
> example is a globally unique IEEE EUI-64 identifier of the form:
>
> ```
>    |0              1|1              3|3              4|4              6|
>    |0              5|6              1|2              7|8              3|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
>    |cccccc0gcccccccc|ccccccccmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> where "c" is the bits of the assigned company_id, "0" is the value of
> the universal/local bit to indicate universal scope, "g" is
> individual/group bit, and "m" is the bits of the manufacturer-
> selected extension identifier. The IPv6 interface identifier would be
> of the form:
>
> ```
>    |0              1|1              3|3              4|4              6|
>    |0              5|6              1|2              7|8              3|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
>    |cccccc1gcccccccc|ccccccccmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> The only change is inverting the value of the universal/local bit.
>
> Links or Nodes with IEEE 802 48-bit MACs
>
> [EUI64] defines a method to create an IEEE EUI-64 identifier from an
> IEEE 48-bit MAC identifier.  This is to insert two octets, with
> hexadecimal values of 0xFF and 0xFE (see the Note at the end of
> appendix), in the middle of the 48-bit MAC (between the company_id and
> vendor-supplied id). An example is the 48-bit IEEE MAC with Global
> scope:
>
> ```
>    |0              1|1              3|3              4|
>    |0              5|6              1|2              7|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+
>    |cccccc0gcccccccc|ccccccccmmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> where "c" is the bits of the assigned company_id, "0" is the value of
> the universal/local bit to indicate Global scope, "g" is
> individual/group bit, and "m" is the bits of the manufacturer-
> selected extension identifier. The interface identifier would be of
> the form:
>
> ```
>    |0              1|1              3|3              4|4              6|
>    |0              5|6              1|2              7|8              3|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
>    |cccccc1gcccccccc|cccccccc11111111|11111110mmmmmmmm|mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> When IEEE 802 48-bit MAC addresses are available (on an interface or a
> node), an implementation may use them to create interface identifiers
> due to their availability and uniqueness properties.
>
> Links with Other Kinds of Identifiers
>
> There are a number of types of links that have link-layer interface
> identifiers other than IEEE EUI-64 or IEEE 802 48-bit MACs. Examples
> include LocalTalk and Arcnet. The method to create a Modified EUI-64
> format identifier is to take the link identifier (e.g., the LocalTalk
> 8-bit node identifier) and zero fill it to the left. For example, a
> LocalTalk 8-bit node identifier of hexadecimal value 0x4F results in
> the following interface identifier:
>
> ```
>    |0              1|1              3|3              4|4              6|
>    |0              5|6              1|2              7|8              3|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
>    |0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000000000000|0000000001001111|
>    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> Note that this results in the universal/local bit set to "0" to
> indicate local scope.
>
> Links without Identifiers
>
> There are a number of links that do not have any type of built-in
> identifier.  The most common of these are serial links and configured
> tunnels. Interface identifiers that are unique within a subnet prefix
> must be chosen.
>
> When no built-in identifier is available on a link, the preferred
> approach is to use a universal interface identifier from another
> interface or one that is assigned to the node itself. When using this
> approach, no other interface connecting the same node to the same
> subnet prefix may use the same identifier.
>
> If there is no universal interface identifier available for use on the
> link, the implementation needs to create a local-scope interface
> identifier. The only requirement is that it be unique within a subnet
> prefix. There are many possible approaches to select a
> subnet-prefix-unique interface identifier.  These include the
> following:
>
> ```
>   Manual Configuration
>   Node Serial Number
>   Other Node-Specific Token
> ```
>
> The subnet-prefix-unique interface identifier should be generated in a
> manner such that it does not change after a reboot of a node or if
> interfaces are added or deleted from the node.
>
> The selection of the appropriate algorithm is link and implementation
> dependent. The details on forming interface identifiers are defined in
> the appropriate "IPv6 over " specification.  It is strongly
> recommended that a collision detection algorithm be implemented as
> part of any automatic algorithm.
>
> ```
> Note: [EUI-64] actually defines 0xFF and 0xFF as the bits to be
>      inserted to create an IEEE EUI-64 identifier from an IEEE MAC-
>      48 identifier.  The 0xFF and 0xFE values are used when starting
>      with an IEEE EUI-48 identifier.  The incorrect value was used
>      in earlier versions of the specification due to a
>      misunderstanding about the differences between IEEE MAC-48 and
>      EUI-48 identifiers.
>
>      This document purposely continues the use of 0xFF and 0xFE
>      because it meets the requirements for IPv6 interface
>      identifiers (i.e., that they must be unique on the link), IEEE
>      EUI-48 and MAC-48 identifiers are syntactically equivalent, and
>      that it doesn't cause any problems in practice.
> ```